# Is There any way to stop tracking "Page Load" in application insights using java script

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a .net webapps on which i am using applicationinsights with web sdk, I want to stop tracking "Page Load" in application insights, is there any way so i can stop it using java script.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking "Page Load" is done by adding the Application Insights javascript SDK snippet in your web pages. The simplest way to stop tracking them is removing that script.

The part that need to be removed can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-javascript/#set-up-application-insights-for-your-web-page) (the explenation in this documentation is how to add it).

Hope this helps,

Asaf

Comment: yes, the easiest way to remove pageviews is to either remove that snippet of code from your pages, or you can remove the line that sets the ikey, if you want to disable it temporarily.

Comment: @JohnGardner Thanks for your help , i did it already but my i was facing issue to how to stop for one server , for ex: i configured it for production, staging and development server but i want to disable it for development for sometime